# Processor replacement

Tags: processor, motherboard, windows, intel

I have a problem with a pc using intel core i7 gen 4. And would like to test it with other pc that using i5 gen 4. Is it Match vice versa with the mother board? And how about the driver installed in windows? Should I update?

Comment: Laptop, or desktop? Laptop PCs have BGA Pentiums which are machine soldered in place and cannot be removed. Only desktop motherboards are practical to change the CPU on. Open a command Prompt and run _wmic computersystem get model,name,manufacturer,systemtype_ then post the result by clicking on [edit] and adding it to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to test a core i5 4th gen cpu in the same Lga 1150 gen motheboard. There should be no problem. As long as it's still a 4th gen cpu on a 4th gen motherboard you will be good. About the drivers, I'd say update to the newest ones you can get, or if you're worried about security (Thank you Windows), rather wait until they are sure about their updates not being able to break your computer

Comment: Cool. Lemme know how it goes if you don't mind? Will help until the problem is solved